# Understanding the circuit

Tags: transistors, bjt, dc-motor, ldr

I am a beginner electronic student and I know this might sound a bit easy for most of you, but I would like to understand the role of the components used in this circuit - it's an LDR-Controlled DC Motor.

So, I know the basic things like the voltage divider between the LDR and the pot and the use of the diode, but I'd like to understand what's the role of the capacitor, the 10k resistor, the BC548 and the TIP32 in the circuit.

[image]

Comment: It's actually a rather poor circuit. R1 performs no useful function, but there should be a resistor in the connection between Q1 and Q2. Also, switching a motor on and off would really benefit from some hysteresis. In other words, this is not a good circuit to learn from. Pick a different one.

Comment: Ok, I will do that, thanks for the advice. But, can you explain me what they were supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

If the LDR resistance got near zero, R1 would limit current through the base-emitter junction of Q1. C1 provides what is called "bulk capacitance" to relieve strain on the power supply to serve transient current demand.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. One more thing, what's the transistor choice criteria and what Q2 is really doing in the circuit?

Comment: Q2 is the "Switch" providing the motor armature current. Q1 controls Q2. Agreeing with idea for some hysteresis, add 10Meg Ohm resistor from collector of Q2 to base of Q1.

Comment: Q2 is the second half of what amounts to a Darlington pair,  which is a pretty common current amplifier topology.

Comment: @vicatcu Q2 is the second half of a 'super alpha' pair, a darlington uses the same polarity of transistor twice